# Не работает onclick() в расширении google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, manifest

Я создаю расширение для google chrome, но когда я его запустил, onclick не работает, хотя в html документе все запускалось.
[image]

Манифест:

```json
{
    "name": "Chrome",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "I",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {"16":"icons/16.ico", "32": "icons/32.ico", "64": "icons/64.ico", "128": "icons/128.ico"},
    "action": {"default_popup": "index.html"},
    "permissions": [],
    "background":{}
}
```